# scraping with Beautiful Soup: print every other value in list off strings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to pull 2019 CFB rankings but every other value is the next week's opponent and not the next team in the ranking. Is there a way to remove every other value without having to index the list?

```
base_site = "http://cbssports.com/college-football/rankings/cbs-sports-ranking/"

response = requests.get(base_site)
response

html = response.content

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

# Find all links on the page 
links = soup.find_all("span", {"class": 'TeamName'})
links

# Inspecting the text inside the links
[link.text for link in links]
```

response:

['LSU',
'UT-San Antonio',
'Clemson',
'Georgia Tech',
'Ohio St.',
'Bowling Green',
'Georgia',
'Virginia',
etc.

With every other team as the ranking I need (LSU hen Clemson, etc.)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shoudl do the trick.

```
names = ['LSU', 'UT-San Antonio', 'Clemson', 'Georgia Tech', 'Ohio St.', 'Bowling Green', 'Georgia', 'Virginia']

names = names[1::2]
```

The second element is chosen by indexing with 1, and then taken at an interval of 2.